# how to populate data in UITableView section by date?

Tags: ios, swift

I have managed to retrieve data from JSON using swiftJSON but I am facing problems when i try to populate tableview.

```
 "results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "email": "",
            "photo": "",
            "cover_photo": "",
            "username": "",
            "name_display": "",
            "location": null,
            "share_count": 0,
            "like_count": 0,
            "subscriber_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0
        },

        "subscribed": false,
        "type": "view",
        "text": "",
        "history_date": "2017-08-07T06:51:19.243391Z"
    }
]
```

I want to build a table view with a section by "history_date"

Comment: I'm not sure this has a huge amount to do with UITableView per se but rather with the data model you use to populate it. If you sort the model by history_date in the way you want and then pass that to the table view it will appear as you want.

Comment: you can even consider organizing the dada in a dictinery ,which the key will be  ever aspecifc date of just a month- year. it realy depend on the sections you want to create

Comment: Update your question with the code you've already tried, otherwise the question needs to be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a nice struct model which will make it much easier. When you try to parse your data try to create your model a class or struct both will work Apple suggests to use structs if you don't want to have references.

```
Struct Result {
    let id: String
    let subscribed: Bool
    let type: String
    let text: String
    let history_date: String
    // Here you can add another struck or class for your user
    let user: User // this can be an array of users as well
}
```

Now create another struct for User

```
Struct User {
    let email: String
    let photo: String
    let cover_photo: String
    let username: String
    let location: Any // I added any but you can change to any format you receives 
    let share_count: Int
    let like_count: Int
    let subscriber_count: Int
    let comment_count: Int
}
```

Once you have your model parsed properly now you can easily access these using dot(.) notations. populate your array of dataModel

```
let results = [Result]() // I assume that you already filled the array.

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.user.count
}

// here comes the magic
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    // remember I am not formatting the date you have to formate the date so it looks the way you want
    return results[section].history_date
}
```

Comment: i have error "value of type [result] has no member 'user'"

Comment: You have to show some simple code so we can see what's wrong